# Why does proguard -keepclassmembers behave differently based on class-specifier?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I've been debugging a ProGuard issue in an Android app I'm writing caused by it removing field names that are needed to extract the fields from a JSON string.  To make sure those members remained with their original names, I added this:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.common.regions.** {
    !static !final !transient <fields>;
}
```

This seemed to work and the output mapping.txt showed the following:

```
com.example.common.regions.RegionMapMeta -> com.example.b.d.b:
    java.lang.String mapVid -> mapVid
    int mapVersion -> mapVersion
    double topLeftLat -> topLeftLat
    double topLeftLong -> topLeftLong
    double topRightLat -> topRightLat
    double topRightLong -> topRightLong
    double bottomLeftLat -> bottomLeftLat
    double bottomLeftLong -> bottomLeftLong
    double bottomRightLat -> bottomRightLat
    double bottomRightLong -> bottomRightLong
    double boundingTopLat -> boundingTopLat
    double boundingBottomLat -> boundingBottomLat
    double boundingLeftLong -> boundingLeftLong
    double boundingRightLong -> boundingRightLong
    int minZoom -> minZoom
    int maxZoom -> maxZoom
    int maxZoomMinX -> maxZoomMinX
    int maxZoomMaxX -> maxZoomMaxX
    int maxZoomMinY -> maxZoomMinY
    int maxZoomMaxY -> maxZoomMaxY
    int stackOrder -> stackOrder
    java.lang.String thumbnailImage -> thumbnailImage
    java.util.Set mapLayers -> mapLayers
```

Then I thought I didn't like having to specify directories in ProGuard and that it would be better to have an annotation to distinguish these classes.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ProguardKeepClassMembers {
}
```

I then annotated my classes (not the members, just the classes) with `@ProguardKeepClassMembers` and changed the ProGuard rule to be as such:

```
-keepclassmembers @com.example.common.ProguardKeepClassMembers class * {
    !static !final !transient <fields>;
}
```

However, this does **not** work the same.  The mapping.txt file has the same fields but now they're being obfuscated.

```
com.example.common.regions.RegionMapMeta -> com.example.b.d.b:
    java.lang.String mapVid -> a
    int mapVersion -> b
    double topLeftLat -> c
    double topLeftLong -> d
    double topRightLat -> e
    double topRightLong -> f
    double bottomLeftLat -> g
    double bottomLeftLong -> h
    double bottomRightLat -> i
    double bottomRightLong -> j
    double boundingTopLat -> k
    double boundingBottomLat -> l
    double boundingLeftLong -> m
    double boundingRightLong -> n
    int minZoom -> o
    int maxZoom -> p
    int maxZoomMinX -> q
    int maxZoomMaxX -> r
    int maxZoomMinY -> s
    int maxZoomMaxY -> t
    int stackOrder -> u
    java.lang.String thumbnailImage -> v
    java.util.Set mapLayers -> w
```

So...  *Why is -keepclassmembers behaving different when only the class matcher has changed*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProGuard is probably removing the annotation itself, since the code is not using it. You should keep it:

```
-keep @interface com.example.common.ProguardKeepClassMembers
```

Alternatively, you can collect such annotations in a jar annotations.jar and specify it as a library (without leaving it in the source code or in libs):

```
-libraryjars annotations.jar
```

The annotation classes then won't be in the resulting code, which is fine. This is the approach from the example examples/annotations/examples.pro (e.g. in android-sdk/tools/proguard).

Also see the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > Unexpected observations after processing > [Classes or class members not being kept](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#notkept).

Comment: Okay, that seems to work, though it does stop ProGuard from obfuscating the `.common` package name everywhere.  Also, links into ProGuard documentation don't work for me -- they always bring me to the top-level frame.  (Chrome v33)